# How to negate the sequences of characters in the positive lookbehind using regexes?

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, lookbehind

Given the following strings:

```
<i>aaa>
<i>aaa>>
<i>AAA>
<i>AAA>>
<i>999>
<i>9>
<i>>
<b>aaa>
<b>AAA>
```

I want to use regular expressions to match one or more final angle brackets `>` if the string contains `<i>` followed by some sequence of characters.

I have tried using the positive lookbehind: `(?<=<i>[A-Za-z\d].*)>.*` in order to ignore the `<i>` and some sequence of characters until the final bracket, but got the error `* A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width`.

How to group the characters inside the positive lookbehind?

Comment: You seem to be using regex101, but where are you going to use the regex, what programming language?

Comment: Yes, I tested it with the regex101 in order to use it later in Python.

Comment: Then  `pip install regex` and enjoy infinite width lookbehind patterns.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the `>` chars at the end of string? Try `re.sub(r'(<i>.*?)>+$', r'\1', text)`

Comment: I am trying to replace them with the ending `</i>` tag.

Comment: Then `re.sub(r'(<i>.*?)>+$', r'\1</i>', text)`, or `re.sub(r'(<i>.*?)>+$', r'\1</i>', text, flags=re.M)`, or - if you need to keep to your pattern, ``re.sub(r'(<i>[A-Za-z\d]*)>+$', r'\1</i>', text)``, see https://regex101.com/r/IBzRrI/1

Comment: show before and after, yes ?

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'(<i>[A-Za-z\d]*)>+$', r'\1</i>', text)
```

Or, a bit more generic:

```
re.sub(r'(<i>.*?)>+$', r'\1</i>', text)   # if there can be anything after <i>
re.sub(r'(<i>[^>]*)>+$', r'\1</i>', text) # if there can be anything but > after <i>
```

Or even

```
re.sub(r'(<i>[^>]*)>+$', r'\1</i>', text, flags=re.M) # To replace at each line end
```

See [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/IBzRrI/1).

**Pattern details**

- `(<i>[A-Za-z\d]*)` - a capturing group that matches and places in Group 1 (its value is referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern) `<i>` and then 0 or more ASCII letters and digits
- `[^>]*` - matches 0 or more chars other than `>`
- `.*?` - matches 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `>+` - 1 or more `>` chars
- `$`  - end of string (or line if `re.M` flag is provided).